# Grab Dynamically Added Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Full code can be viewed on JSBin - http://jsbin.com/ecuraQEg/1/edit

I'm working on an experimental website designer (a wysiwyg editor) and I'm having a bit of trouble.

I want to be able to manipulate divs that have been drawn/appended, via changing it's position, background color, border, padding, etc:

Say I drew 3 divs with the following background color red, green, and blue.

When I click on the red div I want it to display all it's properties, height, width, top, left, background, etc: I already have width and height down, but I can't seem to figure out how to grab the other styles.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

DIVs width/height are grabbed by the following:

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if ($('select#tools option:selected').val() !== 'select') return;

    $('#canvas div').on('mousemove', function() {
        // Detects/Shows div size on specified element.
        $('#elm-width').val($(this).width().toString() + 'px');
        $('#elm-height').val($(this).height().toString() + 'px');
    });

    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    $('#canvas div.rect').draggable();
    code.val(preview.html());
    coder.val(preview.html());
};
```

DIVs are drawn using the following JQuery/Javascript:

```
setMousePosition = function(e) {
  if ($('select#tools option:selected').val() !== 'div') return;
    var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
    if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
        mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
        mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
    } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
        mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    }
};

var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    startX: 0,
    startY: 0
};
var element = null;

// Mouse Event Handlers
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if ($('select#tools option:selected').val() !== 'div') return;
    setMousePosition();
    if (element !== null) {
        element.style.position = $('select#position option:selected').val();
        element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
        element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
        element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
        element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
        element.style.margin = $('#elm-margin').val();
        element.style.padding = $('#elm-padding').val();
        element.style.color = $('#elm-color').val();
        element.style.border = $('#elm-border').val();
        element.style.borderRadius = $('#elm-border-radius').val();
        element.style.MozBorderRadius = $('#elm-border-radius').val();
        element.style.background = $('#elm-bgcolor').val();
        element.style.boxShadow = $('#elm-boxshadow').val();
        element.style.textShadow = $('#elm-txtshadow').val();
        element.style.overflow = 'auto';

        $('#elm-top').val(element.style.top);
        $('#elm-left').val(element.style.left);
        $('#elm-width').val(element.style.width);
        $('#elm-height').val(element.style.height);
    }
};

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    if ($('select#tools option:selected').val() !== 'div') return;
    if (element !== null) {
        element = null;
        canvas.style.cursor = "default";
        console.log("finsihed.");
    } else {
        console.log("begun.");
        mouse.startY = mouse.y;
        mouse.startX = mouse.x;
        element = document.createElement('div');
        element.className = 'rect';
        element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
        element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
        canvas.appendChild(element);
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode($('#insidediv').val()));
        canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
    }
};

canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
    if ($('select#tools option:selected').val() !== 'div') return;
    element = null;
    canvas.style.cursor = "default";
    console.log("finsihed.");
    code.val(preview.html());
    coder.val(preview.html());
    $('.select-tool').trigger('click');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can get the value of any css property using `$(element).css('property-name');`

Here's a quick example using that, as well as using `.offset().top` and `.offset().left` as alternative for getting those values. (These are also jQuery methods):

http://jsfiddle.net/sx8B3/

Comment: Unfortunately that gets a little trickier.. you would need to get the height of the container element `$(container_elem).height()`, and then subtract the top offset and height of the target element from that, to get it's distance from the bottom. Unless of course you have an absolutely positioned element with `bottom` and `right` properties set on it or something like that, in which case you can use the `.css()` method. But I assume this is not the case.